# How to fetch enum attributes using AttrBaseType

Tags: ibm-doors

I want to fetch enum attributes in a module using AttriBaseType and print it's elements.

Basically I want to know the usage of AttriBaseType in dxl.

Comment: Not exactly sure why you want to use AttrBaseType to get enum values, since the Base type of each enumeration is "Enumeration" (`attrEnumeration`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For retrieving enum values, if you really want to use it explicitly, you can do it perhaps like this:

```
AttrType at
for at in current Module do {
    print (at.name) " -- " (at.type) "\n"
    AttrBaseType abt = at.type
    if (abt == attrEnumeration) {
        print "it is an " abt "\n"
        int enumCount = at.size
        int index
        for (index = 0; index < enumCount; index++) {
            // value, related number
            print at.strings[index] ", " at.values[index] "\n"
        }
        print "\n"
    }
}
```